# How to move out of being a support role?

Tags: startup

I work at a smallish start-up as part of the documentation department. I joined the department as a way to get into the organization because I was interested in it. I was able to move around and contribute to different aspects from development, communications, operations etc. However, lately as the teams have started to fill out in these other categories I've found myself becoming more a support role to the new hires as they're given the tasks and responsibilities that before I would handle as part of my catch-all capabilities.

One thing this allows me to do is focus more on the department I'm in specifically but I feel conflicted about this. Although creating great documentation is at the end of the day fulfilling to me, I would like to achieve more than just working on docs. I feel almost as I'm a support character in every one else's stories now (even though I do continue to do my own work as well). I'm relatively early in my career, so is this something common when you start on a team that is small but soon gets bigger? Should I be making a stronger effort for more responsibility?

Answer (score 3):

Talk to whoever you report to. It seems that your core job responsibilities don't align with what you want to do, so figure out what you *do* want to do, and talk to your manager. A discussion can go like this: "Hey, when I started I was able to do X, Y and Z which I really enjoyed, especially Z. Now my role no longer encompasses Z, and I was hoping we could find a way in which I could engage in Z." Bonus points if you can find a way in which you doing Z delivers value to the company.

Ultimately, it may be that what you were hired for is not what you want to do, in which case you'll have to decide if you can be happy with what you're doing, or if its worth it to look for another job where you can get experience relevant to your long term career goals.